# Advanced Python Pandas Dataframe Selection

Tags: python, r, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Suppose you have the following dataframe, built with the code:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *

headers = ['name', 'rating']

data = (['John', .987], ['Joe', .543], ['Mary', .294], ['Bill', .784])

df = Dataframe(data, columns = headers)
```

I understand I can do dataframe selection such as `df.name` or `df[['rating']]` to access a column at a time, or `df[2:3]` for row slicing, but I can't seem to combine both. What if I wanted all rows with higher than a .500 rating? This doesn't seem to work:

```
df[df.rating > .5]
```

or

```
df.where(df.rating > .5)
```

Where the first one would work in R. In the documentation [The where() Method and Masking ()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking), the example is:

```
s.where(s > 0)
```

Yet this is very limiting as we rarely want to select a new object based on all columns and all rows (as a matter of fact, I never have this need). I understand dataframes in Python are not equal to dataframes in R, but the need still remains.

1. How do I select rows that meet certain numeric criteria? Equivalent
   to `df[df.rating > .5]`
2. How do I select rows based on a list? Equivalent to `df[df.name in ('John', 'Joe')]'`
3. Can I slice on both column & row filters? Equivalent to
   `df[df.rating > .5, df.name in ('John', 'Joe')]`

I feel like the help is lacking in advanced slicing whereas R's is superior in [Subsetting](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/subsetting.htm)

Comment: These are all straight out of the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: Thank you - I realized what I was doing wrong. In my example I had demo data which was fine but in my application all the values were str instead of int and was not allowing me to slice as I wanted. Stupid me - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code and this should work:

```
#1:
df[df['rating']>0.5]
#2:
df.query('name in ("John", "Mary")') 
#3:
df.query('name in ("John", "Mary") and rating > 0.5')
```